# Docker login on remote windows machine using ssh

Tags: linux, shell, powershell, docker, ubuntu

I have Installed ssh agent on windows machine and I have powershell script there to build a container.

**MyBuild.ps1**

```
$awslogin = aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-2

Invoke-Expression $awslogin

cd "C:\Buildfolder"

docker build -t newimage .

docker tag newimage 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com:aug2018

docker push 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com:aug2018

echo "Process Completed"
```

I am calling the remote powershell script from linux machine using following command.

```
sshpass -p 'mypasswd' ssh Administrator@X.X.X.X powershell C:/Buildfolder/MyBuild.ps1
```

While running the script i am getting following error for docker ecr login.

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.`
```

While I manually run the powershell script from windows, It works perfectly. Also all other commands through ssh is working expect docker ecr login.

My aim is to build docker image in remote windows machine. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Had *very* similar scenario but not with powershell  - removing  "credsStore" row from `.docker/config.json` helped.

** EDIT **

And for what ever reason, after a reboot this stopped working. Re-removing credsStore didnt help either after that.